# LINQ - convert select sum to a groupby sum

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert some of my SQL queries to LINQ queries.

I have the following SQL query - which basically gets the JourneyStart, Journey End point and joins with all points in between to calculate the distance travelled.

```
DECLARE @utcStartDate DateTime2 = '2017-02-01 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @utcEndDate DateTime2 = '2017-02-02 23:59:59.9999999'
DECLARE @assetId INT = 4019

SELECT 
     AssetId
    ,[Event]
    ,StartDateTime
    ,EndDateTime
    ,JourneyDistance = ROUND(SUM(DistanceCoveredK), 3, 2)
    ,TotalJourneyTime = JourneyTime
FROM (
    SELECT 
         AssetId = ignOn.iAssetId
        ,Startlogid = ignOn.iVehicleMonitoringId
        ,StartDateTime = ignOn.dtUTCDateTime    
        ,Endlogid = ignOff.iVehicleMonitoringId
        ,EndDateTime = ignOff.dtUTCDateTime
        ,[Event] = ignOff.eEventCode
        ,DistanceCoveredK = p.sptGeoLocaitonPoint.STDistance(
                                LEAD(p.sptGeoLocaitonPoint) OVER(PARTITION BY ignOn.iAssetId, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime ORDER BY p.dtUTCDateTime)) * 0.001
        ,JourneyTime = DATEDIFF(SECOND, ignOn.dtUTCDateTime, ignOff.dtUTCDateTime)

    FROM VehicleMonitoringLog ignOn

    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT top(1) iVehicleMonitoringId, eEventCode, dtUTCDateTime, sptGeoLocaitonPoint 
        FROM VehicleMonitoringLog WHERE 
        iAssetId = ignOn.iAssetId AND dtUTCDateTime > ignOn.dtUTCDateTime AND eEventCode = 2
        ORDER by dtUTCDateTime
    ) ignOff

    INNER JOIN VehicleMonitoringLog p ON p.iAssetId = ignOn.iAssetId AND p.dtUTCDateTime >= ignOn.dtUTCDateTime AND p.dtUTCDateTime <= ignOff.dtUTCDateTime
    
    WHERE 
        ignOn.dtUTCDateTime > @utcStartDate AND ignOn.dtUTCDateTime < @utcEndDate
        AND ignOn.iAssetId = @assetId
        AND ignOn.eEventCode = 1
) g

GROUP BY AssetId, [Event], StartDateTime, EndDateTime, JourneyTime
```

When converted to a LINQ query I have come up with the following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var VehicleMonitoringLogs = VehicleMonitoringLog.GetData();

    DateTime _startDate = new DateTime(2000, 02, 01);
    DateTime _endDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 02).AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

    var assetIds = new int[] { 2 };
    // end of params


    var locationLogsWithDistance =
                // first get all location logs based on parameters criteria
                from locationLog in VehicleMonitoringLogs
                                    .Where(s =>
                                            assetIds.Contains(s.AssetId)
                                            && s.LogDateTime >= _startDate
                                            && s.LogDateTime <= _endDate
                                            )
                                    .OrderBy(t => t.LogDateTime)
                    // then for each location log in the above criteria get it's previous position - this is to calculate distance between current position and previous - because a vehicle does not move in a straight line so we need this.
                let prevPosition = VehicleMonitoringLogs
                           .Where(s => s.AssetId == locationLog.AssetId
                                           && s.LogDateTime >= _startDate
                                           && s.LogDateTime <= _endDate
                                           && s.LogDateTime < locationLog.LogDateTime
                                           && s.LogId != locationLog.LogId)
                                           .OrderByDescending(s => s.LogDateTime)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()

                orderby locationLog.LogDateTime

                select new
                {
                    AssetId = locationLog.AssetId,
                    VehicleMonitoringId = locationLog.LogId,
                    EventCode = locationLog.EventCode,
                    LogDateTimeUTC = locationLog.LogDateTime,
                    // calculate distance from previous point and convert from meters to KM
                    DistanceFromPreviousPoint = Math.Round((prevPosition != null ? locationLog.GeoLocationPoint.Distance(prevPosition.GeoLocationPoint) ?? 0 : default(double)) * .001, 2)
                };


    // now once we have a list of location logs with distance from previous record we can start calculating the logic for Journey's.

    var journeyLogs =
                      // get all journey start events (Ignition On or EventCode == 1)
                      from journeyStart in locationLogsWithDistance.Where(s => s.EventCode == 1)

                          // get the corresponding End Event (Ignition Off or EventCode == 2) - so the first Ignition Off after the existing Ignition On Event
                      from journeyEnd in locationLogsWithDistance.Where(s =>
                                                            s.AssetId == journeyStart.AssetId
                                                            && s.EventCode == 2
                                                            && s.LogDateTimeUTC >= journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC)
                                                            .OrderBy(t => t.LogDateTimeUTC)
                                                            .Take(1)
                      select new
                      {
                          AssetId = journeyStart.AssetId,

                          JourneyStartId = journeyStart.VehicleMonitoringId,
                          JourneyStartUtc = journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC,

                          JourneyEndId = journeyEnd.VehicleMonitoringId,
                          JourneyEndUtc = journeyEnd.LogDateTimeUTC,

                          // finally the Distance Travelled is SUM of all distances between each location point between Journey Start and Journey End Events
                          DistanceTravelled = locationLogsWithDistance
                                          .Where(s =>
                                              s.LogDateTimeUTC >= journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC &&
                                              s.LogDateTimeUTC <= journeyEnd.LogDateTimeUTC &&
                                              s.AssetId == journeyStart.AssetId)
                                          .Sum(r => r.DistanceFromPreviousPoint)
                      };

    foreach (var j in journeyLogs)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", j.AssetId, j.DistanceTravelled, j.JourneyStartUtc, j.JourneyEndUtc);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Complete.....");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

The result is correct and as aspected, but the SQL query is doing a new `SELECT` and then `SUM` of the location logs.
So I would like to convert this part to a `group by` statement.

```
DistanceTravelled = locationLogsWithDistance
                                                .Where(s => 
                                                    s.LogDateTimeUTC >= journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC && 
                                                    s.LogDateTimeUTC <= journeyEnd.LogDateTimeUTC && 
                                                    s.AssetId == journeyStart.AssetId)
                                                .Sum(r => r.DistanceFromPreviousPoint)
```

The logic would be to group by `journeyStart.AssetId, journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC` then SUM the `DistanceFromPreviousPoint`. But I can't exactly determine a way or the syntax to do that.

[SAMPLE DATA AND QUERY](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/1273217/calculate-the-total-time-worked-and-total-distance-travelled)

[DOTNET FIDDLE AND C# DATA](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LbZ7pp)

Comment: .GroupBy(x => x.AssetId).Select(x => x.Sum(y => y.DistanceFromPreviousPoint)).ToList().  A groupby creates a two dimensional array [keys, List<object>] so you need a select to enumerate through the keys then a select to enumerate through the object.

Comment: @jdweng I thought of that but I don't have the `journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC ` at that point of time - as I need the distance for each journey seperately - hence the Group By AssetId and journeyStart.LogDateTimeUTC

Comment: Your queries are so convoluted. It's really hard for me to refactor into something that works without having some data to put through and an expected output.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've added some comments to my LINQ query and included a LINK to SQL Query and sample data - if you run that query you should see the expected results in sql. Hope this helps

Comment: @DawoodAwan - Can you please provide the class definitions and your data as valid C# code? I'm not going to do the work to try to build a database, query it, map to an unknown object model, and then run your query. Please make this easy for us to help.

Comment: @Enigmativity added the data code in C# to this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/3JtCce
Think there is too much code for it to work on the fiddle - but copy paste this in a console application and install EntityFramework 6 should get this working

Comment: @Enigmativity do you want me to get the existing query working with the existing data aswell?

Comment: @DawoodAwan - I should be able to copy and paste your code and then get it to run. Can I do that with what you've posted? If not, yes please. ***Please make this easy for us to help.***

Comment: @Enigmativity updated question and dotnet fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/LbZ7pp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it took a bit of mucking around to work out exactly what you were doing, but the complete set of data, classes, and code made it possible.

I ended up writing two helper functions to make this work.

```
double GetDistance(VehicleMonitoringLog log0, VehicleMonitoringLog log1) =>
    (log0.GeoLocationPoint.Distance(log1.GeoLocationPoint) ?? 0.0) * .001;
```

This is just a function to compute distance.

Here's the more complicated one:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> open, Func<T, bool> close)
{
    IEnumerable<T> Output(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        yield return enumerator.Current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
            if (close(enumerator.Current))
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
    var e = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (open(e.Current))
        {
            yield return Output(e).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

This one allows me to take a sequence and partition it into subsequences where there's a starting condition and an ending condition. In your case `EventCode == 1` and `EventCode == 2`.

So, given those, here is my final query:

```
var journeyLogs =
    from s in VehicleMonitoringLogs
    where assetIds.Contains(s.AssetId)
    where s.LogDateTime >= _startDate
    where s.LogDateTime <= _endDate
    orderby s.LogDateTime
    group s by s.AssetId into gs
    from partition in Partition(gs, t => t.EventCode == 1, t => t.EventCode == 2)
    let first = partition.First()
    where first.EventCode == 1 // ensures we start with a 1
    let last = partition.Last()
    where last.EventCode == 2 // ensures we end with a 2
    select new
    {
        AssetId = first.AssetId,
        JourneyStartId = first.LogId,
        JourneyStartUtc = first.LogDateTime,
        JourneyEndId = last.LogId,
        JourneyEndUtc = last.LogDateTime,           
        DistanceTravelled = partition.Skip(1).Zip(partition, (p1, p0) => GetDistance(p0, p1)).Sum()
    };
```

The output I get matches yours.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - Zip is new for me so learnt about that today. Just one final question - would the `Partition` function work fine with `IQueryable`? I don't really want to materialise the list before doing all these calculations.

Comment: @DawoodAwan - No, that's not true. Casting an `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` **and then iterating the collection** will cause the query to run.

Comment: In a way it does - I will try to make it L2E - as loading this much data into Memory won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a very limited programming language and c# is much better.  Never try to use SQL syntax directly in c#.  Look for a better way.  I assumed each journey started with an event 1 and end with an event 2.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime  utcStartDate =  DateTime.Parse("2017-02-01 00:00:00.0000000");
            DateTime utcEndDate = utcStartDate.AddDays(2);
            int assetId = 4019;

            List<VehicleMonitoringLogs> logs = new List<VehicleMonitoringLogs>();

            List<VehicleMonitoringLogs> idDates = logs.Where(x => (x.iAssetId == assetId) && (x.dtUTCDateTime > utcStartDate) && (x.dtUTCDateTime < utcEndDate))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.dtUTCDateTime)
                .ToList();

            var eventOns = idDates.Where(x => x.eEventCode == 2).Select((x,i) => new {endJourney = x, index = i}).ToList();
            var eventOffs = idDates.Where(x => x.eEventCode == 1).Select((x, i) => new { startJourney = x, index = i }).ToList();
            
            var results = (from _on in eventOns 
                          join off in eventOffs on _on.index equals off.index
                          select new { sptGeoLocaitonPoint = .001M * (_on.endJourney.sptGeoLocaitonPoint - off.startJourney.sptGeoLocaitonPoint), JourneyTime = _on.endJourney.dtUTCDateTime - off.startJourney.dtUTCDateTime}
                          ).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class VehicleMonitoringLogs
    {
        public int iAssetId { get; set; }
        public string iVehicleMonitoringId { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtUTCDateTime { get; set; }
        public int eEventCode { get; set; }
        public decimal sptGeoLocaitonPoint { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```